# ld: framework not found Bolts clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: ios, swift, bolts-framework

When I compile and run the code it works fine on iPhone.

However the above error shows up when trying to "Archive" the project.  Why would dependencies pop up when archiving?

Bolts is not in Podfile nor is it in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries".

Comment: No. I had it before but afterwards I removed it.

Comment: I can build it and run it no problem. The issue rises only when archiving, yes.

Comment: No it is not. Actually.

Comment: hope you the best :( i cannot do more in the comment section.. message me if you solve this or dont find an answer fb.com/mrpatrnogic

Comment: Thank you Marcio! That's kind of you. Will try to solve it and will update it if I find a solution.